# MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail() returns null

Tags: android

I have the following code;

```
String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns._ID, MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA };
                //String selection = MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.KIND + "=" + MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.;
                String sort = MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns._ID + " DESC";

                Cursor myCursor = getActivity().managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, sort);


                try
                {
                    myCursor.moveToFirst();
                    Log.d("VIDEO_URI", intent.getDataString());
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                            getActivity().getContentResolver(), myCursor.getLong(myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns._ID)),
                            MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND,
                            (BitmapFactory.Options) null );

                    ImageView iv = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.attached_media_image);

                    //Log.d("IMAGE", curThumb.toString());

                    iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    Log.e("ERROR", e.toString());
                }
```

I get the following in my LogCat when this is ran;

```
03-13 12:05:14.740: D/VIDEO_URI(7269): content://media/external/video/media/474
```

But it doesn't set the image of the iv to anything, and when I try to run the Log.d("IMAGE", curThumb.toString()); line, that is commented out in this example, it throws a null exception.

Any help would be much appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thumbnail generation is not guaranteed to succeed since the part that generates thumbnails cannot do so for some video codecs. The returned `Bitmap` will be `null` in that case.

- Have you checked if `bitmap != null`?
- Do you get a thumbnail for the Video in e.g. the Gallery app?
- What is `curThumb`, I can see no definition of that in your code.

Edit: Your error is that you use the ID from the thumbnails table not the id of the video.
All you need to do is to get the Bitmap this way:

```
        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                getActivity().getContentResolver(),
                ContentUris.parseId(intent.getData()),
                MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND,
                (BitmapFactory.Options) null );
```

Api Doc says: "origId: Original image id associated with thumbnail of interest."

Comment: The `curThumb` variable is left over, that should be the `bitmap` variable.  These videos are taken natively on the device and there are thumbnails in the Gallery application.

I haven't checked if `bitmap != null` because if it's null and passed to `iv.setImageBitmap()` it doesn't throw an exception.  But I know it's the null variable.

Comment: Is null being cast to (BitmapFactory.Options) ?

Comment: @mikbanUtah Yes it looks like that's the case. You can probably just put a simple `null` (or actual bitmap options). Cast was copied from the question.

Comment: `Integer.parseInt` is wrong as ids are `long`s. This is better way to get id: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11488103/360211

Comment: @weston much better indeed. Mainly because it's a library function that works probably better with some edge cases. `int` vs `long` itself will hardly ever matter because ids are all autoincrement and you'll have to load and remove gazillions of files onto your device to break that max_int barrier.