# Get the ID of a new record inserted into a database from the returned Uri

Tags: android, android-sqlite

When you insert a new item into a database like this

```
Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(Tournaments.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

is there any way to get the id from the uri that is returned so I don't have to run a query to get the id since its already in the returned uri?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

[ContentUris.parseId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentUris.html#parseId%28android.net.Uri%29) converts the last path segment to a long.

Comment: ContentUris.parseId() is "official" Google answer on how to retrieve record IDs, see at the end of [Inserting data](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html#Inserting) section.  You can also use uri.getLastPathSegment() to get a string value, but you need to use Long.valueOf(stringId) instead of Integer.valueOf(stringId) because database IDs have long values.

Answer (score 12):

```
long id = Long.valueOf(uri.getLastPathSegment());
```

Comment: does uri.getPathSegments().get(1) also gives the same

Answer (score 1):

Use ContentUris.parseId(uri)
This statement will Converts the last path segment to a long.

Read Documentation in [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentUris.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
long rowId = Long.valueOf(uri.getLastPathSegment());
```

The above is correct. But what I did is, I passed uri like Events.CONTENT_URI.getLastPathSegment() which doesn't give the id. Because we have to pass the URI which is returned by insert() like below. May be helpful to someone like me!

```
Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values); 
long rowId = Long.valueOf(uri.getLastPathSegment());
```