# How to get the id of the last inserted row in the SQLite db using AsynQueryHandler

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am inserting a row in the SQLite DB using `AsyncQueryHandler` and trying to get the `id` of newly inserted row inside `onInsertComplete` method as shown in the `try-catch` bellow but i am getting the exception: `java.lang.NullPointerException: unable to parse 'lectureTimeTable' (this is my table name in which i have inserted a row.)`

I am following [This StackOverflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11488035/1773155)

I want to know a way to get the id of last inserted row in the following situation!

```
AsyncQueryHandler mAsyncQueryHandler = new AsyncQueryHandler(getContentResolver()) {
        @Override
        protected void onInsertComplete(int token, Object cookie, Uri uri) {
            super.onInsertComplete(token, cookie, uri);

            switch (token) {
            case MyConstants.TOKEN_INSERT_LECTURE_TIME:

                try {
                    int newlyInsertedLectureTimeId = Integer.valueOf(uri
                            .getLastPathSegment());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    };
 mAsyncQueryHandler.startInsert(
                    MyConstants.TOKEN_INSERT_LECTURE_TIME, new Object(),
                    CourseLectureTime.CONTENT_URI, lectureTimeCV);
```